# How does a templated class resolve an overloaded non-member function called on one of its types?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

In the following example, I've created a mock Container class for an arbitrary type. Calling compare() on the Container calls compare() for the Value object stored inside. How is the compare() function overloaded for Value resolved in `Container<Value>` when it is declared afterwards and is not a member function of Value?

Code:

```
template<typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(T value) : element(value) {}
    T element;
};

template<typename T>
int compare(Container<T> const& first, Container<T> const& second)
{
    return compare(first.element, second.element);
}

class Value
{
public:
    Value(int value) : value(value) {}
    int value;
};

int compare(Value const& first, Value const& second)
{
    if (first.value < second.value)
        return -1;
    else if (first.value > second.value)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    auto l1 = Container<Value>(1);
    auto l2 = Container<Value>(1);
    auto l3 = Container<Value>(2);

    cout << compare(l1, l2) << endl;
    cout << compare(l1, l3) << endl;
}
```

Output (as expected):

```
0
-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the [argument dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (ADL).

The two arguments of the call `compare(first.element, second.element)` are of type `Value`, so the whole enclosing namespace of `Value`, i.e., the global namespace, is searched, and the overload of `compare` for `Value` is found.

If you replace `Value` by a fundamental type, e.g. `int`, then there is no ADL and the code won't work:

```
template<typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(T value) : element(value) {}
    T element;
};

template<typename T>
int compare(Container<T> const& first, Container<T> const& second)
{
    return compare(first.element, second.element); // error: no matching function for call to 'compare(const int&, const int&)'
}

int compare(int first, int second)
{
    if (first < second)
        return -1;
    else if (first > second)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    auto l1 = Container<int>(1);
    auto l2 = Container<int>(2);

    compare(l1, l2);
}
```

Comment: This is really interesting to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Templates only get resolved when they are instantiated so your `compare` `Value` method just needs to be declared before `main` not before your `compare` `Container` method